# Conjugate directions and parameterized linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is SPD and $P = (p_1,...,p_m) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ consists of $A$-conjugate directions and is obtained from the CG. We know for the solution to the $Ax = b,$ we have the approximation $Py,$ where $(P^T A P)y = P^T b.$

Denote $A_k = A+kI.$ Consider the equation $(P^T A_k P)z = P^T b$ and $Pz$ is an approximation to the solution of $A_k x=b.$

Are there any related known results on the bound of $\|Pz-x\|$ or $\|Pz - P_k \tilde{z}\|,$ where $P_k$ are $A_k$-conjugate directions obtained from the CG and $\tilde{z}$ is the solution to $P_k^T A_k P\tilde{z} = P_k^Tb.$ If so, could you please recommend some liturature?

---

In general, if we use a collection of $A$-conjugate directions as basis to solve other systems $\tilde{A}x=b$ ($\tilde{A}$ is "close" to $A$), what's the error bound?